# Databricks SQL Warehouse connect to PostgreSQL: unsupported data source error

Tags: postgresql, connection, databricks, databricks-sql

I'm trying to connect my Azure postgresql database from Databricks SQL Warehouse.

According to the docs I tried:
https://docs.databricks.com/query-federation/postgresql.html
[image]

https://docs.databricks.com/external-data/jdbc.html#read-data-with-jdbc

[image]

But getting error for both cases:
**The input query contains unsupported data source(s).Only csv, json, avro, delta, parquet, orc, text, unity_catalog data sources are supported on Databricks SQL.**

I assume that connection reaches the database because if I put any of parameters wrongly, e.g. non existing table I receive corresponding error.

Please advise what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Query federation functionality right now is in the private preview - that means that it should be explicitly enabled for your account/workspace (via your Databricks representative). Public preview was mentioned in the [January's quarterly roadmap webinar](https://www.databricks.com/p/webinar/productroadmapwebinar) as tentatively happening in Q2.

Comment: I see, thanks.. But what about JDBC option, is it relevant or any other possibilities to connect the postgresql exist?

Comment: Connection still happens via JDBC… but the main thing is that driver needs to be installed into warehouse

Comment: It appears that issue was in the warehouse type - it was Classic initially. I upgraded it to Pro and command with using JDBC executed successfully. But then a new issue occurs: when I try to select from the newly created view I see the error: The table or view postgresql_vw cannot be found. The view is absent in metadata as well..

Comment: Additional notes: I tried this JDBC create temp view command against SQL notebook - the view is created and data is available as expected. I have no idea why SQL Warehouse has the issue.. @Alex Ott, appreciate if you have any ideas

Comment: Interesting. I may need to look. But right now that feature is marked as experimental - I hope that we'll get better version soon, built into the Unity Catalog

Comment: Hello, @Alex Ott, did you have a chance to take a look into this issue? Having access to postgresql table is crucial requirements, which might stop up from using SQL Warehouse in our production at all..

Comment: I would recommend to open support ticket for that